# Saving a html file to public_html

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I have a small Flask application that runs fine locally, however when I go to run the application on my server, it runs but I am not able to get the output to save to a public_html folder.

This is the area I believe I am having the issue, when I run the application remotely:

```
df.to_html('/home/mydomain/public_html/data/candles.html', index = False)
```

If I run the application locally, this location works fine:

```
df.to_html('candles.html', index = False)
```

I have ensured that the remote folder 'data' has full access - 0777.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post errors from Flask console or web logs.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an exception occurring, then very likely the file was saved, but not where you think it should have. If you did not provide a full path, the destination will be relative to the application directory. The solution is to be explicit and provide a full path, unless you are using some Flask functions that already have a default setting.

You should never grant 0777 permissions on public_html, that is a potential vulnerability. For example, someone could upload a shell to that directory if they can leverage a security flaw on your website.

There is not enough context, but the user running the process (Apache, Nginx or whatever) should not have write permissions here. If you must grant write permissions, create a dedicated directory (preferably outside the webroot unless they have to be exposed to the user), then add some directives to stipulate that files present in the directory cannot be executed. So that even if a webshell is uploaded it cannot run.